Solve an integral equation using functional analysis
I'm trying to solve the following equation:
Is there a continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$$f(x) + \int_0^x e^{x \cos(t)}f(t) \ dt = x^2 + 1, x \in [0,1]$$ if so, check if it is unique.
We were also given the hint to check if -1 is in the spectre of the operator.
I tried several approaches; I tried using $x^2+1$ as $f$, but it didn't work. My next approach was to show that the norm of the operator is less than 1, which would imply that -1 is not in the spectre, but that didn't work either.
Could you please give me a hint as to which approach I should use here. Thank you.

I am not very much into spectral analysis. Do you mind explaining what the operator actually is? And btw, have you tried $f(t)=1$?

Can you use differential equations? If so, first, notice that $f$ is actually more than continuous, it is differentiable (infinitely). Second, if you differentiate the equation, you should get an ODE. I'm hoping this can help.

@cnikbesku As far as I understand, it's $ U(f):= \int_0^x e^{x \ cos(t)} f(t) \ dt $, a linear map of the space $C[0,1]$. I tried $f = 1$, but then we get a difficult integral that doesn't seem to be equal to $x^2$...

@StefanLafon I can use differential equations! I'm not sure if it will work, since the integral gets even more complicated after the differentiation, but I'll try to look at this equation using this way, thanks!

This is a special case of a Volterra integral equation. There is an existence and uniqueness theorem for this kind of equation which follows by a standard application of Banach's fixed point theorem. You can take a look at Kreyszig's Functional Analysis, Chapter 5 if all you need is to prove existence and uniqueness of a solution. I have no idea how to construct a solution, if that's what you need.

Have you learned about Fredholm operators?

@Thomas no. This is just a regular functional analysis problem (at least in our course)

Consider $\mathcal{L}(f): C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ given by:
$$\mathcal{L}(f)(x)=x^2+1-\int_0^xe^{x\cos(t)}f(t)dt$$
Our problem now translates into finding a fixed point for this operator. Notice that:
$$|\mathcal{L^2}(f)(x)-\mathcal{L^2}(\psi)(x)|\leq\int_0^x e^{x\cos (t)}|\mathcal{L}(f)(t)-\mathcal{L}(\psi)(t)|dt\leq$$
$$\int_0^x e^{x\cos(t)}\int_0^te^{t \cos(u)} \lVert f-\psi \rVert_\infty du dt=\lVert f-\psi \rVert_\infty\int_0^x\int_0^t e^{x\cos(t)+t\cos(u)}dudt $$
One more application yields:
$$|\mathcal{L}^3(f)(x)-\mathcal{L}^3(\psi)(x)|\leq\int_0^xe^{x\cos(t)}|\mathcal{L^2(f)}(t)-\mathcal{L}^2(\psi(t))|dt\leq$$
$$\lVert f-\psi\rVert_\infty\int_0^x\int_0^t\int_0^{t_1}e^{x\cos(t)+t\cos(t_1)+t_1\cos(u)}dudt_1dt$$
Surprisingly this is still not good enough for us, but the pattern is clear:
$$|\mathcal{L}^4(f)(x)-\mathcal{L}^4(\psi)(x)|\leq\lVert f-\psi\rVert_\infty \int_0^x\int_0^t\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{t_2}e^{x\cos(t)+t\cos(t_1)+t_1\cos(t_2)+t_2\cos(u)}dudt_2dt_1dt=I\lVert f-\psi\rVert_\infty$$
This is enough for our purposes because once we notice $g(t_2)=t_1\cos(t_2)+t_2$ is increasing for $t_2\in[0,t_1]$ $0\geq t_1\geq 1$ and so is $h(t_1)=t\cos(t_1)+t_1\cos(t_1)+t_1$ for $t_1\in[0,t]$ $0\geq t\geq 1$ :
$$I\leq\int_0^1\int_0^t\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{t_2}e^{\cos(t)+t\cos(t_1)+t_1\cos(t_2)+t_2\cos(u)}dudt_2dt_1dt\leq$$
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^t\int_0^{t_1}t_2 e^{\cos(t)+t\cos(t_1)+t_1\cos(t_2)+t_2}dt_2dt_1dt
\leq
\int_0^1\int_0^t\frac{t_1^2}{2} e^{\cos(t)+t\cos(t_1)+t_1\cos(t_1)+t_1}dt_1dt\leq\int_0^1\frac{t^3}{6} e^{\cos(t)+2t\cos(t)+t}dt\approx 0,5404...<1$$
Thus $\lVert \mathcal{L}^4(f)-\mathcal{L}^4(\Psi)\rVert< C \lVert f-\Psi\rVert$ where $C<1$ and $\mathcal{L}^4$ is a contraction between Banach spaces frow which it follows that $\mathcal{L}^{4k}(f)\rightarrow \psi_o$ tends to a unique fixed point $\psi_o$ whenever $k\rightarrow \infty$. In particular we may take $\mathcal{L}^j(\mathcal{f})$ as our initial point for $j=0,1,...,3$ which yields:
$$\begin{cases}\mathcal{L}^{4k}(f)\rightarrow \psi_o\\
\mathcal{L}^{4k+1}(f)\rightarrow \psi_o\\
\mathcal{L}^{4k+2}(f)\rightarrow \psi_o\\
\mathcal{L}^{4k+3}(f)\rightarrow \psi_o\\
\end{cases}$$
This is enough for us to conclude that $\mathcal{L}^{k}(f)\rightarrow \psi_o$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. $\psi_o$ must be a fixed point of $\mathcal{L}$ by continuity of $\mathcal{L}$. Furthermore, this fixed point of $\mathcal{L}$ is a fixed point of $\mathcal{L}^4$ which is unique by Banach's fixed point Theorem. Hence, $\psi_o$ exists and is unique.

This defintely has nothing to do with the spectre of the operator (which you were given as a hint) and my solution mimicks the proof of Picard's Theorem in ODE. Indirectly though we are using something like $r(T)=\lim \lVert T^n\rVert^{1/n}$... (In our case, $n=4$ was enough for our intentions.)
